# What's the difference between experience and fame?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I just got level 20 with my mage and the top bar just changed from experience to fame. The odd thing is that fame seems to be always at the same level, it never increases.

Who can explain what's happened? Is level 20 the maximum? And how to increase fame?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fame is used as a kind of currency in the game.  You get fame in a number of ways, usually by killing boss or god class enemies, being in a party with other people when they level up, or being more accurate with your attacks.  20 is the level cap.